# Display link to npm package under Packages section in github repo

Tags: javascript, node.js, github, npm

I just created and published my first [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@mayank1513/vue-tag-input).

[image]

I want to link this package to my GitHub repo. Under packages it shows `Publish your first package`. However, on many repo I see that it shows link to their npm package there.

How do I link this to npm package. Also I read something about github package registry. Can I publish my package there as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout documentation at https://docs.github.com/en/packages/quickstart

We need to create a .github/workflows directory. In that directory, create a file named release-package.yml.

Comment: Just to be sure, but there is apparently no way to just link NPM and then the packages simply appear? We have to 'republish' to Github Packages in a way?